# Remove excess padding inside select element in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to remove styling from `select` elements using CSS. For example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HTseX/

No matter what I try, there is extra padding between the border of the element and the text, mainly in IE8. Firefox, Chrome and IE9 are simliar to each other, but IE8 is taller.

I'm guessing it just isn't possible. I always try to use the same code in all browsers, so I'm try to make sure I actually need to do specific coding for IE8, or use JS pulldowns.

Thanks.

Comment: did you use a css reset before adding any styles?

Comment: @MikeB, yes I am using a CSS reset. GionaF, I expect to be able to remove the excess padding between the text and the container.

Answer (score 0):

> The select renders slightly differently depending on the browser and operating system in use, and is well known as a troublesome HTML element to style with CSS (because the display is inherited from the operating system, rather than provided by the browser).

[Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/select)

Comment: yeah I understand that. I've got everything else worked out the way I want it, but this is the last bit I need to figure out before I write browser specific code.

Comment: div, select, option {padding: 0; margin: 0; font-size: normal; line-height: normal !important!;}

Comment: I tried that in my version and jsfiddle, the only addition being `line-height: normal !important;`, but also adding it to the option, and it doesn't have any impact. Did that work for you in the jsfiddle?

Comment: What that appears to do is make the select taller in Chrome so there's not as much difference between Chrome and IE8. However, it makes it considerably taller in Firefox.

Comment: Right. @GionaF has a better option. Sorry.