# Looking for a CSS fix for IE

Tags: css

Found this cool little tutorial for styling drop down menus using  CSS. You can change everything about the box - border, font, background colour etc including the drop down arrow. Ive made a custom drop down arrow to suit the style of the site. It all works fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. On Opera the box style remains but the arrow reverts back to the default. I can live with this.

However are good ole friend Internet Explorer is the problem. It also reverts back to the default arrow but a portion of my custom built arrow is visible underneath the the default arrow.

Anyone any ideas on how I can fix this? **Tested version is IE 9**

Here's a link code & css: http://tinkerbin.com/mD2vfqLQ

And some screenshots of the different browsers: http://ScrnSht.com/sqrnlh

Comment: Oh man IE ? :( .. hmm version?

Comment: @Murali Ive only tried it on 9

Comment: where is the "cool little tutorial"?

Comment: @jawad Do i detect a hint of sarcasm in that question?? :-))

Link: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Comment: LOL. Offcouse not. Just wanted to know on what you based you code. Just might learn something new.

Comment: The select renders slightly differently depending on the browser and operating system in use, and is well known as a troublesome HTML element to style with CSS (because the display is inherited from the operating system, rather than provided by the browser). - http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/select

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751577/remove-excess-padding-inside-select-element-in-ie8/12751639#12751639

Answer (score 1):

Have a conditional CSS class:

```
<!--[if IE]>
.select_style select {
    background-image: none !important;
}
<![endif]-->
```

change it to `<!--[if lte IE 8]>` if it is a specific version of IE

Comment: this is the full css can you give me a url from which you are viewing it and i can try some things out

Comment: sorry dude pretty new to this. How can I give you url when site isnt live?

Comment: this is what I have put together so far: http://testing.dpwebdev.co.uk/stackoverflow/cus-select/ - and in ie versions 7-9 it looks ok.